# Как изменить  href  и добавить впереди редирект cпомощью jQuery или яваскрипта.

Tags: jquery, redirect, javascript

Как изменить href  и добавить впереди редирект некоторым ссылкам с помощью jQuery или яваскрипта. Все ссылки находятся в классе «quote».  Получится должно примерно так `http://mysite.com/redirect.php?url=http://site.com`

Answer (score 3):

мне решение видится таким:

`$(function(){
   var redirect='your_redirect';
   $('a.quote').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('href', redirect+$(this).attr('href'));
   });
});`

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('quote'),
        redirect = 'redirectString';
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        var href = links[i].href;
        links[i].href = redirect + href;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, Серёг, благодаря тебе нашёл ошибку у себя))

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю перед этим передаваемую в строке адреса строку необходимо экранировать.